# Dynamically display database information onclick

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, memcached

I set up a web service using LAMP for personal use.
Basically, I have a scrollable list with some database information I pull once in the PHP script. I'd like to be able to click on one of the items, and have more information appear in a preview pane . (preview pane is set up)

I don't expect to ever have more than 100 entries in my database. Also, the data I'm pulling is very small...about 10 fields, all text data.

My question is as follows:
If I pull all the data I need in one shot, how can I store it so that each block of data I define (2-3 rows are what I need in the preview pane) is "cached" and I can access that given block at will so I can display it upon clicking its corresponding list entry?
Basically, this is about the same as clicking an email in a web-browser and having the rest of the message show up in a preview pane.

Thanks.

nb: the fact that I'm using a preview pane or a list is irrelevant. Just describing what I'm doing.

Comment: please provide a code example of what you have tried so far

Comment: Download everything into the DOM, and use `display: none` and `display: block` styles to hide and show elements as you click on them. This is reasonable for small tables like you describe, you would want to use more dynamic AJAX for a something larger.

Comment: If I'd tried anything, I would have posted it. All I have done is make a Mysql call and assign all the rows and fields I need to various variables that are then used to populate an HTML list.

Comment: if you try and provide some code to accompany your question, it is much easier to answer it in your own terms so the answer would be more helpful

Comment: @Barmar, does downloading into the DOM mean writing it to a XML file?

Comment: You can use XML, HTML, JSON, whatever you like. You might want to take a look at plugins like jqGrid.

Comment: @user2993778: The DOM we're talking about is an internal "image" of a website that your browser uses: it's created from the source files by parsing and it can be modified by Javascript for example. For more accurate definition and history, visit http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to create a simple page, where several details are hidden until you click on different buttons. If you would like to do this in a "cached" way, you can try the following:

1. Fetch the complete data so that everything (with details) ends up in the result HTML. Everything: I mean, the parts which should be visible at all times and also the details which should be visible only after pressing a button.
2. Now, to the design. You will have to write CSS code, which will hide the details. (Of course, for that, you will have to create HTML in step 1 which will let you target the details via CSS classes, for example.) You will also have to figure out how to create buttons.
3. The most complicated part is to bind the buttons to Javascript actions, which will perform showing the hidden details. You can control all CSS properties from Javascript, so for example you can alter the position, the size, the text color etc. of a `<div>` dynamically.

Most people nowadays use jQuery for tasks like the one in step 3, or even software libraries built on the top of jQuery. That could help a lot if you're just starting out with tasks like this one. On the jQuery site, you will find a great place to start, called the [jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/).

**Edit: I've created a very basic fiddle to let you test the JS part of my concept, see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/eL9mj/22/**

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to get it.But how can I know which list element I'm clicking on, considering that they're generated dynamically? Do they need to be numbered in some way ? Furthermore, where do I store the data that I'm not displaying right away? I'm confused about what a DOM is.

Comment: Please see my comment on the question, it will tell you more about the DOM.

Comment: I meant that you should output all the data into the HTML and hide those temporarily in a visual way - I don't know whether this rephrasing will help you. With CSS, you can hide parts of the HTML output for example.
After checking jQuery, you will see how easy it is to get the information about the element which was clicked - it won't be an issue at all.

Comment: To be able to visualize what's happening, here's a jQuery example: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-show-and-hide-example/ - try pushing the show() and hide() buttons.

Comment: Thanks. But any ideas on how I can "pair" the data in the list and the data that's supposed to go in the preview area so I know what to activate?

Comment: @user2993778 I've added a fiddle to the answer to show you how, please check it.